# Scrapy extracting after certain <p>

Tags: python, scrapy

Say I have a structure like that;

```
<div id="body">
<h1> Title </h1>
<p> Date Created </p>
<p class="text-bold"> Description </p>
<p> Para1 </p>
<p> Para2 </p>
<p> Para..</p>
<p> ParaN </p>
```

I am trying to get Para1 to ParaN appended together. To add onto it, Para1 in certain links might be placed as `//p[5]` and sometimes as `//p[6]`.

So by running a default of,

```
def parse_details(self, response):
        item = response.meta["item"]
        item['Message'] = response.xpath('//p[x]/text()').extract()

        yield item
```

It will sometimes fail and return a wrong field as `x` is somewhat dynamic. What stays constant is that I need all fields under `<p class="text-bold"> Description </p>`.

Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you need all fields after `<p class="text-bold"> Description </p>` you can simply try xpath [`following-sibling`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657223/xpath-get-following-sibling9) function

```
html = """
<div id="body">
<h1> Title </h1>
<p> Date Created </p>
<p class="text-bold"> Description </p>
<p> Para1 </p>
<p> Para2 </p>
<p> Para..</p>
<p> ParaN </p>
"""

from scrapy import Selector
sel = Selector(text=html)
xpath = "//p[contains(text(), 'Description')]/following-sibling::p/text()"
r = sel.xpath(xpath).extract()
print(r)
# [u' Para1 ', u' Para2 ', u' Para..', u' ParaN ']
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked well. I seem to find the Scrapy documentation a bit difficult to understand. But hopefully I am able to burn in more. Any ideas where I can learn more about the syntax and examples?

Comment: this is not really Scrapy, this is xpath documentation. I agree xpath docs suck. I found microsoft xpath docs useful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx mdn has a page too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath Remember you can always use css selectors (they are better documented but xpaths are sometimes more powerfull), response.css() is always an option in Scrapy

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Will definitely explore further.