# Clicking on a button using Python with Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web, button

I want to click on the following button:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifiDC.png

So far my code looks like this, but nothing happens:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cgi5v.png

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: can you print the value of find_element_by_css_selector ?

Comment: Please avoid to post snapshot.These are more confusing to OP to provide you solutions.Post html in text format and as well code.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Do the following:

1. Using @class='fl-product-size--item fl-product-size--item__not-available you can create a unique locator.
2. If Only @class do not provide you unique locator you can take help from [Parent-Child RelationShip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237694/xpath-get-parent-node-from-child-node) or [Sibling Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657223/xpath-get-following-sibling).
3. Creating Unique locator is the main thing.Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use xpath as CSS locator have three elements for the same.

I checked the xpath in website, as 48 size is not available ,but xpath is like that

```
//button[@class='fl-product-size--item fl-product-size--item__not-available']//span[text()='48']
```

Comment: This is what my code looks like now. Still doesn't work :/.
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/main/Downloads/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://www.footlocker.de/de/p/adidas-am4-thanos-herren-schuhe-80563?v=314205818504#!searchCategory=herren/schuhe/running')
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="fl-product-size--item"]//span[text()="48"]').click()