# requests-html: find td by content

Tags: python, python-requests-html

So I'm trying to scrape this table using requests-html:

```
<table class="pet-listing__list rescue-details">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Rescue group:</td>
<td><a href="/groups/10282/Dog-Rescue-Newcastle">Dog Rescue Newcastle</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>PetRescue ID:</td>
<td>802283</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Location:</td>
<td>Toronto, NSW</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="first age">Age:</td>
<td class="first age">1 year 2 months</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="adoption_fee">Adoption fee:</td>
<td class="adoption_fee">$550.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="desexed">Desexed:</td>
<td class="desexed"><span class="boolean-image-true boolean-image-yes">Yes</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="vaccinated">Vaccinated:</td>
<td class="vaccinated"><span class="boolean-image-true boolean-image-yes">Yes</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="wormed">Wormed:</td>
<td class="wormed"><span class="boolean-image-true boolean-image-yes">Yes</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="microchip_number">Microchip number:</td>
<td class="microchip_number">OnFile</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="rehoming_organisation_id">Rehoming organisation:</td>
<td class="rehoming_organisation_id">R251000026</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The docs don't seem to mention a way to find the next td e.g. if I want to scrape the dog's rescue group or location. Is there a way to scrape those cells of the table using only requests-html or would this need to additionally go through e.g. bs4/lxml/etc. to be parsed?

Code so far (returns an error as HTMLSession.html.find doesn't take an attribute text like bs4):

```py
class PetBarnCrawler(DogCrawler):
    """Looks for dogs on Petbarn"""
    def __init__(self, url="https://www.petrescue.com.au/listings/search/dogs"):
        super(PetBarnCrawler, self).__init__(url)
    def _get_dogs(self, **kwargs):
        """Get listing of all dogs"""
        for html in self.current_page.html:
            # grab all the dogs on the page
            dog_previews = html.find("article.cards-listings-preview")
            for preview in dog_previews:
                new_session = HTMLSession()
                page_link = preview.find("a.cards-listings-preview__content")[0].attrs["href"]
                dog_page = new_session.get(page_link)
                # populate the dictionary with all the parameters of interest
                this_dog = {
                    "id": os.path.split(urllib.parse.urlparse(dog_page.url).path)[1],
                    "url": page_link,
                    "name": dog_page.html.find(".pet-listing__content__name"),
                    "breed": dog_page.html.find(".pet-listing__content__breed"),
                    "age": dog_page.html.find("td.age")[1],
                    "price": dog_page.html.find("td.adoption_fee")[1],
                    "desexed": dog_page.html.find("td.desexed")[1],
                    "vaccinated": dog_page.html.find("td.vaccinated")[1],
                    "wormed": dog_page.html.find("td.wormed")[1],
                    "feature": dog_page.html.find(".pet-listing__content__feature"),
                    "rescue_group": dog_page.html.find("td", text="Rescue group:").find_next("td"),
                    "rehoming_organisation_id": dog_page.html.find("td.rehoming_organisation_id")[1],
                    "location": dog_page.html.find("td", text="Location:").find_next("td"),
                    "description": dog_page.html.find(".personality"),
                    "medical_notes": dog_page.html.find("."),
                    "adoption_process": dog_page.html.find(".adoption_process"),
                }
                self.dogs.append(this_dog)
                new_session.close()
```

Comment: Can you share what you have worked out so far?

Comment: Edited to include my code so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I didn't read the documentation carefully enough.

Using the xpath query function in requests-html should be sufficient without the need to use a library like bs4 or lxml to traverse the document tree:

```py
{
    ...
    "location": dog_page.html.xpath("//tr[td='Location:']/td[2]")[0].text,
    ...
}
```

cf. this post: [XPath:: Get following Sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657223/xpath-get-following-sibling)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should address your concern.

```
tr = table.findAll(['tr'])[3]
```

[3] specifies the location.

##Updated:09/25

After reviewing the site some more and looking through the tags, the location details you are looking for is stored in the following tag. 'cards-listings-preview__content__section__location'

This piece of code allows me to scrape the location details from the site.

```
location = soup.find_all('strong', attrs={'class':'cards-listings-preview__content__section__location'})
```

Comment: My problem with this approach is that it might break if there are more rows or the rows are rearranged somehow on a different page. Does requests-html *itself* offer any methods analogous to e.g. find_next in bs4, or finding by element content (like in xpath)?

Comment: One you have the loop to fetch table data, you can also search for specific words in the row. In your example based on the input, it would be "Location"

Comment: @JamesHarrison I posted an updated code that will allow you to get specifically the location details. Can you test modify your code with the reference method and tell me if it works.