# Why doesn't my XPath expression return any results?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation

I have the following html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
      <tr>
      <tr>
      <tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Color Digest </td>
        <td>AgArAQICGQMVBBwTIRQHIwg0GUMURAZTBWQJcwV0AoEDAQ </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Color Digest </td>
        <td>2,43,2,25,21,28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,33,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the following xpath:

```
tr[td='Color Digest']/td
```

and I'm getting zero results.
Can someone explain why?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `xPath` expression we can use attribute name and tag name(when it has text) as well. Here both `<tr>` and `<td>` are tag names. The valid `xPath` expressions be like,

```
//tagname[@attributeName='value']
```

and

```
//tagname[@tagname='text']
```

---

Inside `td` there is only text available so you need to write `xPath` like

```
//td[text()='Color Digest ']
```

or

```
//tr[td='Color Digest ']
```

If you need to use specific element then please use the match number like below,

```
(//td[text()='Color Digest '])[1]
```

or

```
(//tr[td='Color Digest '])[1]
```

---

**Why it showed `0` matches for your `xPath`?**

You haven't given **space** at end of `Digest`.

**Yours**:

```
//tr[td='Color Digest']/td
```

**Corrected one**:

```
//tr[td='Color Digest ']/td
```

Comment: But what with the ‘tr’ that I want to be a parent?

Comment: `tr` is parent tag even with parent tag you can construct `xPath` `//tr//td[text()='Color Digest ']`

Comment: Thanks a lot. But i am looking on another post in the forum and see that it should work:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657223/xpath-get-following-sibling.  Can you explain why it is working there?

Comment: Apologies.. I updated my solution.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few issues with your XPath

```
tr[td='Color Digest']/td
^ 1
   ^ 2
                     ^ 3
```

1. XPaths should start with a `/` (child) or `//` (descendant). Child basically means one level down where descendant means one or more levels down.

   `tr` should be `//tr` in this case since there are no root TRs.
2. You've used `td` when it looks like you meant to use `.` or `text()` which indicates two variations of text within the element. `.` means squash the contained text of all descendant nodes and `text()` means the contained text of just the current node.

   Either `text()` or `.` will work in this case but I would generally use `text()` just to be safe.

   `[td='Color Digest']` should be `[text()='Color Digest']`
3. If you look at the HTML you provided, the text in the first TD actually contains a space at the end, e.g. 'Color Digest ' vs 'Color Digest'. That space is required unless you use a function like `contains()`.

   `[td='Color Digest']` should be `[text()='Color Digest ']`
4. For this last one, I'm not sure what you are actually looking for, `/td`.

   For the TD that contains the "Color Digest " text, it has no child. If you meant sibling TD, that would require `/following-sibling`.

   `/td` should be `/following-sibling::td[1]`.

Putting all of this together,

```
//tr[text()='Color Digest ']/following-sibling::td[1]
```

and it would return the following elements

```
<td>AgArAQICGQMVBBwTIRQHIwg0GUMURAZTBWQJcwV0AoEDAQ </td>
<td>2,43,2,25,21,28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...</td>
```